# If f is differentiable at one point of R, then prove that f is differentiable on R.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f$ be a function defined on $R$ such that $$f(x+y) = f(x)+f(y),  x, y  \in R$$ If $f$ is differentiable at one point of $R$, then prove that $f$ is differentiable on entire $R$.

Here $R$ is Real Numbers Set.

I am doing calculus course in graduation.

Please give me some hints on how to solve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

Let the function be differentiable at $x = a \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $$f'(a)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0 } \frac{f(h)}{h}$$
exists.

Given the above fact, check whether $f'(x)$ exists or not.

Comment: That suffices.  Clear and concise.  (+1)